# Does equality of the complexifications imply equality of the algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be two real Lie algebras. Now suppose their complexifications are isomorphic, that is, $$\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}.$$.

Can I say anything about the "isomorphicness" of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$? i.e. do I necessarily have $$\mathfrak{g}\simeq\mathfrak{h}$$

Specifically I am curious about whether $$\mathfrak{su}(4)_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathfrak{so}(6,\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{so}(6,\mathbb{R})_\mathbb{C}$$ implies $$\mathfrak{su}(4)\simeq \mathfrak{so}(6,\mathbb{R})$$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_(Lie_theory)

Answer (score 4):

A simpler counterexample in dimension $3$ is $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$. We have $$\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}\cong\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}),$$
but $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ are not isomorphic as real Lie algebras, because one algebra has a $2$-dimensional subalgebra, the other one does not.
If we furthermore assume that the real Lie algebras are *simple*, then we can use the machinery of the real classification, i.e., that we have one compact real form and one split form etc. The classification result in dimension $3$ for the simple real Lie algebras then is exactly $\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2):

I've constructed a counter example.

$$so(3,1)_\mathbb{C}\simeq so(4,\mathbb{C})\simeq sl(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{C})=su(2)_\mathbb{C}\oplus su(2)_\mathbb{C}=(su(2)\oplus su(2))_\mathbb{C}$$

but it is not true that $so(3,1)\simeq su(2)\oplus su(2)$. In particular one is compact and the other is non-compact.

However, $so(4)\simeq su(2)\oplus su(2)$, so perhaps $g_\mathbb{C}\simeq h_\mathbb{C}$ implies $g\simeq h$ only if $g$ and $h$ are both compact, but I have not proven this.